# Safari Warning On Certificate

Tags: facebook, safari, certificate, warnings

We have recently started receiving warnings from Safari: "Safari can't verify the identity of the websites 's-static.ak.facebook." The certificate for the website is invalid. You might be connecting to be 's-static.ak.facebook' which could put your confidential information at risk. Would you like to connect to this website anyway?"

How do address the issue with our certificate? we don't see what we are doing wrong. Is this an issue with Facebook or us? Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Try another browser ..

Answer (score 0):

Check the date and time of your computer are correct, alot of the time messed up dates cause browsers to think certificates can't be verified or are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57538839-263/safari-users-hit-by-facebook-certificate-error/ there is a whole article about it.

You can see a screenshot of the certificate message from safari, you can click on "Always trust ..."

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a problem in your PC/your browser.

If it is a problem, what it seems to be, then it's a problem of what sits in the facebook address and of how Safari works.

If it bothers you, try switching to a better Browser. But basically, many browsers will alert you on thing like that (perhaps not on the same things, but mostly they will).

Edit: I've just looked into this, and it seems like there's some Image causing the problem.

See more information [here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57538839-263/safari-users-hit-by-facebook-certificate-error/).